# How to check if any of the elements in an array are the same, in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, element

Thus far, I have find(diff(A)==0), however this only proves useful if the elements are adjacent. I am wondering how identify whether or not a number occurs more than once within an array, regardless of position.

Thanks in advance for your time and help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. If `A` is your matrix

```
C = unique(A);
```

`C` will contain the unique elements of `A` so if the length is the same you have all unique elements. If you want to test a specific value trya

```
c = sum((A == value)
```

which will return the number of elements in `A` equal to `value`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is (given some matrix A):

```
length(unique(A))<length(A(:))
```

If any of the elements are the same the output of this line will be 1.